# Finding all possible combinations with repitition of selected items allowed

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a List of objects, The number of these objects is dynamic.I need to find all possible combinations of these objects.

I currently am at a stage where I take a list of objects , and return all possible combinations without repitition using the following code :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Say, inputList contains randomObject1,randomObject2 and randomObject3 
        List<List<RandomObject>> AllCombos = ItemCombinations(inputList);

    }

    //maxComboCount denotes the maximum number of elements that can be in the combination
    public static List<List<T>> ItemCombinations<T>(List<T> inputList, int maxComboCount)
    {
        
        int nonEmptyCombinations = (int)Math.Pow(2, inputList.Count) - 1;

        List<List<T>> listOfCombinations = new List<List<T>>();
        

        for (int i = 1; i <= nonEmptyCombinations; i++)
        {
            List<T> thisCombination = new List<T>();
            for (int j = 0; j < inputList.Count; j++)
            {
                if ((i >> j) % 2 != 0)
                {
                    thisCombination.Add(inputList[j]);
                }
            }

            if (thisCombination.Count <= maxComboCount)
            {
                listOfCombinations.Add(thisCombination);
            }
        }                     
        return listOfCombinations;
    }
```

How do I get all the other combinations where the items are repeated , the maxComboCount will always be there otherwise my required scenario might get stuck in an infinite loop (Correct me if I'm wrong).

> E.g. InputList : {r1,r2,r3}
>
> Current stage : {r1},{r2},{r3},{r1,r2},{r2,r3},{r3,r1},{r1,r2,r3}
>
> Wanted stage (given maxComboCount constraint = 4) : {r1},{r2},{r3},{r1,r1},{r1,r2},{r1,r3},{r2,r2},{r2,r3},{r3,r3} {r1,r1,r1}, {r1,r1,r2} ,{r1,r1,r3},{r1,r2,r3} and so on...

One thing I tried was,

I iterated till maxBaseCardCount and added the inputList at each iteration to another tempList, I then passed this tempList as a parameter in the ItemCombinations method.

```
     //The loop will be constrained by the maximum number of objects allowed
        for (int i = 0; i < maxComboCount; i++)
        {
            tempList.AddRange(inputList);
        }

       List<List<RandomObject>> AllCombos = ItemCombinations(tempList);
```

This was supposed to be a fast and dirty work around, and does give me my required output (with a lot of duplicate values) but I am not very sure about how much it can hold before breaking. So, any approach more reliable than my one will be much appreciated.

**Edit**

I am adding an explanation of the problem, please let me know if any other simplification is required

> InputList : It is a list of objects from which combinations are to be made
>
> ItemCombinations: This function returns all combinations from a given list without repitition (not what I want)
>
> For an inputList = {1,2}, ItemCombination returns : empty, {1},{2},{1,2} i.e. all 2^n unique combinations from any given list of length n

Now, I want this to combine the items with repetitions allowed and the length of combinations dynamic.

Example :

> E.g. InputList : {r1,r2,r3}
>
> ItemCombination function originally returns : {r1},{r2},{r3},{r1,r2},{r2,r3},{r3,r1},{r1,r2,r3}
>
> Now, what I want is , all the combinations that can be made, if there was no limit on how many times each object could be used
>
> What I want (given maxComboCount constraint = 4) : {r1},{r2},{r3},{r1,r1},{r1,r2},{r1,r3},{r2,r2},{r2,r3},{r3,r3} {r1,r1,r1}, {r1,r1,r2} ,{r1,r1,r3},{r1,r2,r3} and so on...
>
> The maxComboCount constraint makes sure that the no list with size>4 is returned
>
> Basically , I want a combination of k objects chosen from n objects, where k can range from 1 to x (any number)

Comment: What do you mean by "possible combinations without repetition"? do you mean permutation or something else?

Comment: Could you write what you want exactly in plain English? I do not want to check your code in order to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: "my required scenario might get stuck in an infinite loop" That means you are doing something wrong, since with or without repetition of elements, the number of combinations if always finite (although it can get very big very fast).

Comment: @oerkelens If I have three objects and I allow repetition, without providing any constraint on how many total objects can be there in the required list, there is nothing to stop the code from making a combination with infinite repititions. That's why I thought it might get stuck

Comment: That is why you need to be more clear about what you want. The normal interpretation of "without repetition" would be 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321, with repetition would be 111, 112, 113, 121, 122, 123, 131.... - meaning repetition of items in each sequence. So what repetition are you talking about, are items allowed to be repeated or not? Please edit your question with that information, giving examples.

Comment: @Nuri Tasmedir. Could you please look at it now and suggest anything

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the combinations of drawing up to `m` items from a pool of `n` items with repetition. Order doesn't matter in the sets of items, so that `{1, 2, 2}` and `{2, 2, 1}` are equivalent; only one of them should be added. (Ideally, this is the one where the items are in ascending order.)

Suppose you have a pool of three items and want to create sets of up to two items. Add the empty set to your results:

```
{}
```

Create sets of one item by iterating the sets with no items and the item pool and adding items:

```
{} + {1} = {1}
{} + {2} = {2}
{} + {3} = {3}
```

Now create sets of two items from the sets with one item, but only add items when they are equal to or larger than the last and largest item in each set:

```
{1} -> {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}
{2} -> {2, 2}, {2, 3}
{3} -> {3, 3}
```

Now you have a set of T(1) + T(2) + T(3) = 10 items:

```
{}
{1}, {2}, {3}
{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}
```

(T(n) is the nth triangle number, ¹ ⁄₂·n·(n + 1).)

I don't know C#, but in pseudo-code, your algorithm looks like this:

```
var m = 3                                   // max. items
var pool = {1, 2, 3}                        // item pool
var res = {{}}                              // results,
                                            // start with empty list

var k = 0                                   // starting index of subarray
                                            // with one fewer item

while (m--) {                               // loop m times
    var kk = res.length()                   // current result array length

    for (var i = k; i < kk; i++) {
        var j0 = 0

        if (res[i].length() > 0) {          // find index of largest item
            j0 = pool.index(res[i].last())  // from the set in pool
        }

        for (var j = j0; j p in pool {      // add new set
            res.add(res[i] + {pool[j]})
        }
    }

    k = kold
}
```

This can also be implemented recursively, where you keep track of the last item index in each level, so that you don't have to search it.